# How to change values in the common elements between 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df called df1 like this:

```
        NAME       CODE       TYPE ........... many other columns
        object1   20052020     A
        object2   20082021     B
        object3   20012031     B
        object4   20010123     C
           .         .         .
           .         .         .
           .         .         .
          etc       etc       etc
```

and i have another df called df2:

```
         NAME      CODE    ........... many other columns
        object1  20052020
        object2  20082021 
           .         .
```

I want to change the TYPE values in df1. I want to make this change only in the common elements between df2 and df1 BY CODE, like this (i changed A type for F type in the common elements):

```
        NAME       CODE       TYPE ........... many other columns
        object1   20052020     F
        object2   20082021     F
        object3   20012031     B
        object4   20010123     C
           .         .         .
           .         .         .
           .         .         .
          etc       etc       etc
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html join them and then do row by row manipulations

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2['CODE'], on='CODE', how='left', indicator=True)
df1.loc[df1.pop('_merge').eq('both'), 'TYPE'] = 'F'
```

OR use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html),

```
df1['TYPE']=(
    df1['CODE'].map(
        df2.set_index('CODE').assign(TYPE='F').pop('TYPE'))
    .fillna(df1['TYPE'])
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

    NAME    CODE     TYPE
0   object1 20052020    F
1   object2 20082021    F
2   object3 20012031    B
3   object4 20010123    C
```

Comment: yep, merge with indicator seems more concise....thanks.

Comment: @Javier Does this answered your question? If so consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
df.set_index('CODE', inplace=True)
df1.set_index('CODE', inplace=True)

df.loc[df.index & df1.index, 'TYPE'] = 'F'
df.reset_index()
```

---

```
CODE        NAME    TYPE                
20052020    object1 F
20082021    object2 F
20012031    object3 B
20010123    object4 C
```

---

Don't forget to reset the index